# bootstrap tooltip - adding tooltip dynamically

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I have a select list with three options.

When the user chooses any option in the select list, a bootstrap tooltip is attached to the select list, and the tooltip is only displayed when the user hovers over the select list.

**The issue I have is that the tooltip only displays when the user selects the option of 0 or 9999.**

I cannot understand why the tooltip does not display for the 8888 option of the select list.

I have checked my code, read the [tooltip docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips) and searched SO & Google.

I am hoping that someone else can point out my error. *This may be a stupid error on my behalf - but I just cannot see it.*

Here is my HTML select list code:

```
<select id="id_professional_development_display_type" name="professional_development_display_type" data-original-title="" title="" class="input-xlarge7">
    <option value="0">Display standard Professional Development Details</option>
    <option value="8888">Display only Description with prompt</option>
    <option value="9999">Display only Description without prompt</option
</select>
```

Here is my jquery code (the following function is called when the page loads and when the select list changes):

```
function displayToolTipMessage() {

    if ($('#id_professional_development_display_type').val() != '0' ) {

        $('#id_professional_development_display_type').tooltip('destroy');
        $('#id_professional_development_display_type').tooltip({'html': true, 'title': 'The Display Type is used to customize how you can display your Professional Development Details.<br /><br />Only the Description will be displayed with this selection!', 'trigger': 'hover'});

    } else {

        $('#id_professional_development_display_type').tooltip('destroy');
        $('#id_professional_development_display_type').tooltip({'html': true, 'title': 'The Display Type is used to customize how you can display your Professional Development Details.<br /><br />This selection will display all the entered Professional Development Details.', 'trigger': 'hover'});

    }

}
```

Comment: can you make demonstration at : http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: How do you use displayToolTipMessage?

Comment: Lajos Arpad - the `displayTollTipMessage` function is called when the page is 1st loaded and also called when the select list changes, like this: `$('#id_professional_development_display_type').change(displayToolTipMessage);`